# Reading return value of JSF action method in JS

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I've got a simple commandbutton which fires an action method in a backing bean.
This method returns a string. In some cases null, in some cases an explicit navigation.

```
 <p:commandButton value="Button" action="#{obj.submit}" onstart="PF('busy').show();" oncomplete="PF('busy').hide()">
```

In case navigation is triggered, I want to show a popup. But how can I check if the method returns an empty string / null ?

Comment: in your return (submit) method you get the case that made it null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this

```
<p:commandButton value="Button" action="#{obj.submit}">
```

And in your method "submit" you have to make the assessment of the case

```
public String submit(){
your code
....
if (value!=null){
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('busy').show();"); 
return value;
} else {
return value; 
}
}
```

Comment: Interesting how I knew of this possibility and ignored it somehow. Thanks!